# following tutorial for publisher and subscriber : missing liblog4cxx.so

Tags: ros, catkin-make, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to catkin_make the catkin_ws folder i get the following output:

```
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/testros/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/testros/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num
[  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts
[ 30%] [ 46%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[ 61%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
[ 84%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_eus
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.so', needed by '/home/testros/catkin_ws/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/listener'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.so', needed by '/home/testros/catkin_ws/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/talker'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:721: recipe for target 'beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listener.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listener.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1128: recipe for target 'beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/all] Error 2
[ 84%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Is it a problem with my ROS installation? I tried rosdep install liblog4cxx, but it did not find anything.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221474/following-tutorial-for-publisher-and-subscriber-:-missing-liblog4cxx.so/) by [JonasV](https://answers.ros.org/users/25170/jonasv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmiles19](https://answers.ros.org/users/26411/mmiles19/) on 2016-03-28**:
Did this ever get solved? I'm having the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosdep install liblog4cxx` is not the correct syntax (confusing I know). You'd need to do `rosdep install beginner_tutorials` (this only works if `beginner_tutorials` is on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`) or `rosdep install --from-paths /home/testros/catkin_ws/src` to install all dependencies for all packages in your catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonasV](https://answers.ros.org/users/25170/jonasv/) on 2015-11-25**:
Doesn't seem to change anything. I tried:

```
rosdep check beginner_tutorials: All system dependencies have been satisified
rosdep resolve log4cxx: #apt liblog4cxx10-dev
rosdep what-needs log4cxx: rosconsole
rosdep where-defined log4cxx: raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
```

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-11-26**:
I don't know then, it seems something is suggesting the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.so` should be linked against, but it doesn't seem to exist. You can check to see if that file exists and if it does not look at the files installed by the `liblog4cxx10-dev` deb.